# Accessing data from Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

Let's say I have a model defined as such

```
class BlogPost(Models.Model):
    """ Defines a blog model """
    blog    = models.TextField()
    blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author  = models.CharField()
```

I want to define some method that accesses the blog posts of a certain author, say 'john doe'. How would I go about defining a method to access all of the blog posts owned by john doe, and then put their blog_id's into a python list?

```
def selectPostsByUser(user):
""" Implement function to select all object """
```

NOTE: please disregard the poor representation of the data fields. They are purely arbitrary, I just put names to remove ambiguity from the example.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have a Foreign Key to user in your model:

```
def selectPostsByUser(user):
    return self.objects.filter(user__id=user.id).values_list('blog_id', flat=True)
```

If the user which you are passing to the `selectPostsByUser` method is the author (and User model object). Then you should have author as a ForiegnKey field in your model.

Comment: yes `__` is intentional and that is how field lookups works. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Answer (score 1):

models.py

```
class BlogPost(Models.Model):
    """ Defines a blog model """
    blog    = models.TextField()
    blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author  = models.CharField()

    @classmethod
    def selectPostsByUser(cls, user):
        return cls.objects.filter(author=user)
```

views.py

```
user = "john doe"
blogs = BlogPost.selectPostsByUser(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `author` field should be a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), not a `CharField`. This is how you represent relationships in Django.

Django then allows you to retrieve the post objects associated with an user: `user.blog_set.all()`. From there, it is trivial to extract the IDs.

Also, Django [automatically provides an `id` field for objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), you don't need to define your own `blog_id` field.

---

Following [the Django "polls" tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) should give you all the tools you need to build your app.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question directly, let's say that the author is actually a 'CharField'. You could just do the following to get all blog posts from 'jane doe' and then put all the IDs into a list....

```
posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(author='jane doe')
list = []
for items in posts:
    lists.append(items.blog_id)
```